# What is the role of Project Owners group in Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm new with Gerrit.

I installed version 2.1.8 on my local machine to poke. My role is Administrators

I see a group named Project Owners that I can't add user to this group.

What is the role of this group? How to add user to this group?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Project Owners is a common placeholder for capabilities of the Owner groups in the context of a particular project.

You can set a group to be Owner of a particular reference in a specific project:

*Access -> Add reference -> Add permission ... -> Owner*

Next, select a group name to be included among the owners. The selected group will inherit Project Owners capabilities on the project reference.

See [Gerrit Owner documentation](http://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.8.2/access-control.html#category_owner) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Project Owners is a virtual group.  You cannot add members to it, or include it in other groups.

According to the [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#project_owners):

> Access rights assigned to this group are always evaluated within the context of a project to which the access rights apply.